# How to do console.log(data) outsite .subsrcibe()

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Let me ask some of these questions. console.log (data) in the subscribe function has data but outside it does not. Now I want to display the api data outside the jaw, then how

```
this.http.post('apisails.azsolutions.vn/api/users/login';,{
 email:this.usernameApi,password:this.passwordApi
}).subscribe(data => {
 this.data=data;console.log(data)
}); console.log(this.data);
```

Comment: Please post code as text not as image. To your problem, the call is made asynchronously so the data is simply not yet available when you try to write it.

Comment: Api call is asnc once api gets succeed you can access the same data out side.(do not for get to bind using `this` inside subscribe)

Comment: this.http.post('http://apisails.azsolutions.vn/api/users/login',{email:this.usernameApi,password:this.passwordApi}).subscribe(data => {this.data=data;console.log(data)});
  
  console.log(this.data);

Comment: create a function outside the subscribe and pass it as a argument to the function when data comes!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function_1() {
  this.http.post('apisails.azsolutions.vn/api/users/login';,{
     email:this.usernameApi,password:this.passwordApi
    }).subscribe(data => {
     this.data=data;
     this.function_2(data);
    });
}

function_2(data) {
  console.log(data);
  // Your Code here
}
```

the .subscribe function is async so , you don't get data instantly,